# ajax, mysql добавление вызова функции в другую функцию

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

```js
<script>
function checkAvailability() {
        $("#loaderIcon").show();
        $("#Check").on("click", function(){
            jQuery.ajax({ 
                url: "check_availability.php", 
                data: { username: $("#username").val(), date_order: $("#date_order").val()},
                type: "POST",
                success:function(data,insertUsername){ 
                    $("#user-availability-status").html(data);
                    $("#user-availability-status").html('Username was added successfully');
                }, 
                error:function (){} 
            });

        function insertUsername() { 

            jQuery.ajax({
                url: "add.php", 
                data: { username: $("#username").val(), date_order: $("#date_order").val() }, 
                type: "POST",
                success:function(data){
                    $("#user-availability-status").html('Username was added successfully');
                },
                error:function (){}
            });
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Как добавить запуск второй функции в первую?)

```
<?php
require_once("dbcontroller.php");
$db_handle = new DBController();


if(!empty($_POST["username"]) && !empty($_POST["date_order"])) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO name VALUES username='" . $_POST["username"] . "' AND
            date_order='" . $_POST["date_order"] . "'

    ";


           $result = mysql_query($sql);
           if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) { 
               echo "<span class='status-notavalibale'> stol zaregan</span>";
           }
           else{ 

               echo "<span class='status-notavalibale'> stol zaregan</span>";
          } 

}
else{

    echo "Одно из полей пустое";

}
$result = mysql_query($sql) || die(mysql_error());
?>
```

Comment: да, запускать insertusername в success. проверка, потом добавление

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    function insertUsername() { 
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: "add.php", 
            data: { username: $("#username").val(), date_order: $("#date_order").val() }, 
            type: "POST",
            success:function(data){
                $("#user-availability-status").html('Username was added successfully');
            },
            error:function (){}
        });
    }

function checkAvailability() {
    $("#loaderIcon").show();
    $("#Check").on("click", function(){
        jQuery.ajax({ 
            url: "check_availability.php", 
            data: { username: $("#username").val(), date_order: $("#date_order").val()},
            type: "POST",
            success:function(data,insertUsername){ 
                $("#user-availability-status").html(data);
                $("#user-availability-status").html('Username was added successfully');
                insertUsername();
            }, 
            error:function (){} 
        });
    });   
}
```

Однако лучший вариант Вашего кода:

```
function insertUsername() { 
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: "add.php", 
            data: { username: $("#username").val(), date_order: $("#date_order").val() }, 
            type: "POST",
            success:function(data){
                $("#user-availability-status").html('Username was added successfully');
            },
            error:function (){}
        });
    }

    function checkAvailability() {
        $("#loaderIcon").show();
    }

    $("#Check").on("click", function(){
        checkAvailability();
        jQuery.ajax({ 
            url: "check_availability.php", 
            data: { username: $("#username").val(), date_order: $("#date_order").val()},
            type: "POST",
            success:function(data,insertUsername){ 
                $("#user-availability-status").html(data);
                $("#user-availability-status").html('Username was added successfully');
                insertUsername();
            }, 
            error:function (){} 
        });
    });

<?php 
    if(!empty($_POST["username"]) && !empty($_POST["date_order"])){
        $username = $_POST["username"];
        $date_order = $_POST["date_order"];
        $sql = "INSERT INTO `name` (username, date_order) VALUES ('$username', '$date_order')";
        $result = mysql_query($sql) || die(mysql_error());
        if(!$result){
            echo "<span class='status-notavalibale'> stol ne zaregan</span>";
        }
        else{ 
            echo "<span class='status-notavalibale'> stol zaregan</span>";
        }
    }
    else{
        echo "Одно из полей пустое";
    }
?>
```

Comment: пишет, что данные добавлены, но в базе пусто:(

Comment: 2 вариант не работает

Comment: да я щас тестирую, данные не добавляются add.php if(!empty($_POST["username"]) && !empty($_POST["date_order"])) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO name VALUES username='" . $_POST["username"] . "' AND
            date_order='" . $_POST["date_order"] . "'
           
    ";

Comment: @илья по sql - name замените на `name`. замечание - нельзя сразу данные из $_POST отправлять в запрос, без обработки,  ваш сайт взломают.

Comment: я добавил, посмотрите. не работает You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '. VALUES username='555' AND date_order='2015-10-13'' at line 1 Check date_orde

Comment: @илья [давайте продолжим обсуждение в чате, нажмите на эту фразу, чтобы перейти в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30219/discussion-between-alex-and-)